# Nested loops-keep the number of iterations constant

Tags: python, while-loop, indices

By request by @mypetition I am editing my question, although I think that the astronomy details here are unimportant.
I have a file of the form:

```
   a          e        q          Q          i        lasc       aper      M          H      dist   comment     i_f      i_h      i_free
45.23710   0.1394   38.93105   51.54315    5.0300    19.9336   286.2554   164.9683   8.41   51.3773   warm     0.000    62.000     4.796
46.78620   0.1404   40.21742   53.35498    3.1061   148.9657   192.3009   337.5967   7.37   40.8789   cold     0.000    42.000     2.473
45.79450   0.1230   40.16178   51.42722    8.0695   104.6470   348.5004    32.9457   8.45   41.3089   warm     0.000    47.000     6.451
42.95280   0.0145   42.32998   43.57562    2.9273   126.3988   262.8777   163.4198   7.36   43.5518   cold     0.000   161.000     2.186
```

There are 1.6e6 lines in total. These are orbital elements. I need to compute the Minimum Orbit Intersection Distance (MOID) between each pair of orbits, e.g line 1 with line 2, line 1 with line3 and so forth until I reach the end of the file. Then, I start from the second line and go to the end of the file. Then start from the third line and agin go to the end of the file etc. Since I have 1.6e6 orbits, that would be `~1e12` orbit pairs.

I don't want to load all these 1e12 calculation on 1 cpu and wait forever, so I am planning to use a cluster and launch multiple serial jobs.

I need to iterate over `1.6e6` elements, where I start with the first elements and go to the end of the file, then start from the second and go to the end of the file etc, until I lastly start with `T-1` and go to `T`. These will result in `10^12` iterations and I am planning split them into multiple jobs, where each job does `C=10^7` calculations, so I can run them on a computer cluster.
I came up with the following nested loop:

```
for i in range( M, N)
  for j in range( i+1, T)
```

where `M=1` and changes according to the number of jobs that I will have. `T=1.6e6` is constant (number of lines to iterate over). I want to find the index `N`, so that the total number of operations is `C=10^7`. Here is how I approached the problem:
`[T-(N+1) + T-(M+1)]*(M-N+1)/2=C`  - because the number of the operations are just the sum of the arithmetic series above. So, I solve the quadratic equation and I get the roots. Here is the python code for that:

```
import numpy as np
import math

C=1.0e7  # How many calculations per job do you want?
T=1.6e6  # How many orbits do you have?
M=1      # what is the starting index of outer loop?
#    N = end index of outer loop (this is to be calculated!)
P=1
l=0
with open('indx.txt','w') as f:

   while P<T:
      l=l+1
      K=np.roots([-1,2*T,M**2-2*T*(M-1)-2*C])
      N=int(round(K[1]))

      f.write("%s %s\n" % (P,P+N))
      M=K[1]+1
      P=P+N+1
```

However, keeping the above solutions, updating M=M+N, I noticed that the condition C=10^7 is not satisfied. Here is a list of the first few indices.

```
M N

1 7
8 21
22 41
42 67
68 99
100 138
139 183
184 234
235 291
 ....
 ....
1583930 1588385
1588386 1592847
1592848 1597316
1597317 1601791
```

But if you look at the pair before the last, the loop over `i=1592848 - 1597316` and `j=i+1, T` will produce more calculations than `C=10^7` i.e roughly (2685+7153)*4468/2 ~ 2.2e7.

Any idea on how to solve this problem, keeping C=1e7 constant, which will provide the number of jobs (with similar running time) I need to run in order to iterate over 1.6e6 lines.

Hopefully, this explanation is enough according to @mypetition standards and am hoping to resolve the problem.

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to rephrase what problem you're facing? It's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: Edit your question with your clarification. Don't post it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the nature of each job can lend itself to a different kind of split but if they do, you could try to use the same trick that Gauss used to come up with ∑1..n = n(n+1)/2

The trick was to line up the sequence with a reversed copy of it:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  
8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1 
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  = 8 * 9 is twice the sum so (8*9)/2 = ∑1..8 = 36
```

Based on this, if you split the pair of series down the middle, you will get 4 pairs of runs that will process the same number of elements:

```
1  2  3  4    
8  7  6  5  
-- -- -- -- 
9  9  9  9
```

Sou you would have 8 runs separated in 4 jobs. Each job would process n+1  (9) elements and compute two runs that have a complementary number of elements

```
Job 1 would do run 8..8 and run 1..8 (length 1 and 8)
Job 2 would do run 7..8 and run 2..8 
Job 3 would do run 6..8 and run 3..8
Job 4 would do run 7..8 and run 4..8
```

In more general terms:

Job i of (N+1)/2 does runs (N-i+1)..N and i..N

If individual runs can't be parallelized further, this should give you the optimal spread (practically the square root of the total process time)

in Python (pseudo code):

```
size = len(array) 
for index in range((size+1)//2):
    launchJob(array, run1Start=index, run2Start=size-index-1)
```

*note: you may want to adjust the starting points if you're not using zero based  indexes.*

*note2: if you're not processing the last element on its own (i.e. N..N is excluded), one of your jobs will have N elements to process instead of N+1 and you will have to make an exception for that one*

Adding more jobs will not significantly improve total processing time but if you want fewer parallel jobs, you can still keep them fairly equal by grouping pairs.

e.g. 2 jobs : [ 1,8,2,7 ] and [3,6,4,5] = 18 per job

Ideally your number of jobs should be a divider of the number of pairs.  If not, you will still get a relatively balanced processing time by spreading extra pairs (or runs) evenly over the other jobs.  If you choose to spread runs, select the ones in the middle of the list of pairs (because they will have individual processing times that are closer to each other).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I meant to run my jobs in serial, not parallel. So for each job I will have i=M, N, J=i+1, T where I want each job to have similar number of calculations e.g. 1e7. For example, the first job will be something like this: i=1,8, J=i+1, 1.6e6 which will give roughly 1e7 calculations. The second job should start from 9 i.e i=9,X, J=i+1, 1.6e6 and so forth until M < T, where I need to figure X.